# Solspace: Calendar Month by Category

Tags: categories, solspace, calendar

The exp:calendar:cal tag appears to completely ignore both category parameters:

{exp:calendar:cal category_url_title="{segment_4}" date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"}

If we also set the calendar_id, then we get zero results, and we know the content is there and assigned to categories.

We really want to use categories to sort events so a single event could be assigned to multiple categories.

Anyone know the secret to making the secret to getting this tag to sort results by category?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Calendar and EE are you using? Also, there is no `category_url_title=""` parameter in `{exp:calendar:cal}`. The parameter for categories is **`category=""`**: http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/calendar/#category

Comment: Ah... I think I was reading this part to mean that it works with either category="" OR category_url_title="", but I'm betting that what it's really saying is that the parameter is smart enough to figure out if it's looking at an ID number or a the cat's URL title. I'll go and give that a try.

Comment: <old:saying>Hot Dog!</old:saying> That's it. Just needed someone to knock me out of an old well established thinking pattern. Thanks so much!